# Update Query that Lists Rows Not Updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a 12 million row SQL Server table that when I run the following query it shows approximately 11.6 million rows updated:

```
UPDATE [HCRIS]
SET [HCRIS].[ST_ABB] = dbo.[PRVDR_CHANGE].[state_abbreviation]
FROM [HCRIS]
INNER JOIN dbo.[PRVDR_CHANGE]
ON [HCRIS].[PRVDR_NUM] = dbo.[PRVDR_CHANGE].[PRVDR_NUM]
WHERE [HCRIS].[PRVDR_NUM] = dbo.[PRVDR_CHANGE].[PRVDR_NUM];
```

I have checked for nulls and non-numeric values in a numeric column but would love to pinpoint those rows that were not updated. My intent is to update all rows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find rows that won't get updated - where you select all rows in the first query and rows you would have updated in the second.

```
SELECT H.*
FROM [HCRIS] H

EXCEPT

SELECT H.*
FROM dbo.[HCRIS] H
INNER JOIN dbo.[PRVDR_CHANGE] C
ON H.[PRVDR_NUM] = C.[PRVDR_NUM]
WHERE H.[PRVDR_NUM] = C.[PRVDR_NUM];
```

Comment: I ran the suggested query (above) and it identified a text value in a numeric row.  I deleted the row with the text value thinking that the update query would now run on all 12 million rows but it did not.  Is there a query that identifies all cells with information inconsistent with data type? Thank you so much for your initial suggestion and any that may follow.

Comment: That would be a different question. This query will identify all rows now being updated by your update statement, which is as asked.

Comment: Understand.  Thank you very much for responding.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  I always try to play by the rules so as to keep access to this valuable information.  I frequently search stack for answers but haven't submitted many questions. I simply neglected to do my end of the process.  I appreciate the follow-up and support. Thank you.